# Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module [Firebase - Reactjs]

Tags: reactjs, firebase

El problema principal es este, lo muestra en la consola de Chrome:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Lo único que he hecho es crear un proyecto con `npx create-react-app year-in-pixel-react` e instalé con npm firebase, sin embargo me muestra el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así estoy importando firebase en el archivo ***App.js***: `import firebase from 'firebase/app'`

Sin embargo he probado también con:
`import {firebase} from 'firebase'`
`import firebase from '@firebase/app'`

Pero el problema persiste, Este es mi ***package.json***

```
{
  "name": "year-in-pixel-react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "type":"module",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^8.3.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-firebaseui": "^4.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "0.9.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Cabe recalcar que al momento de lanzar el proyecto con `npm start` no muestra ningún error o warning.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrarnos en qué parte de `App.js` estás llamando a `Firebase`? Tal vez el error tenga que ver con eso.